# HTML - How do I assign a text value to another attribute's value?

Tags: html

I am trying to assign a HTML `text` attribute's value to a `hidden` attribute's value.

The `text` code:

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" onBlur="myno=this.value; concatno=myno.concat('0001')" />
```

I've used `alert` to try the output of the `concatno` value. For example, if user enter 1010, then the output will be 10100001.

Then my `hidden` code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" value=concatno>
```

I want my `hidden` value to be 1010001, but instead the value became "concatno". How should I assign the value in my `hidden` attribute?

Comment: Without the full code, it's will be hard :(

Comment: You need Javascript for that, you can't just magically reference things and expect them to work.

Comment: @Jimbot actually there are just 2 lines of codes, i'm just doing some testing

Comment: @hatched ok, it was all in the blur, I didn't get it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you never updated your `#hide` element.
You need to use some javascript, for example:

```
document.getElementById('hide').value = concatno;
```

Working snippet:

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" onkeyup="var myno = this.value; var concatno = myno.concat('0001'); document.getElementById('hide').value=concatno;" />
<input id="hide" name="hide" value=concatno disabled>
```

Note that even if the event is not the issue here, I suggest you to use another trigger, like `onkeyup`, so that the value is updated more often.

I've also changed your `hidden` element to `disabled` to make it visual.

Moreover, you should learn to avoid inline JavaScript.
Here is how I'll do it:

```js
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  document.getElementById('hide').value = this.value.concat('0001');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" />
<input id="hide" name="hide" value=concatno disabled>
```

Documentation: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I removed the DV, but it's worth noting that the issue was not because of the event.

Comment: @BenM I agree, but it appeared to me that keyup was more efficient here.

Comment: i'm not sure why but my value becomes "concatno"

Comment: @hatched I can't say. Did you try both of my snippets ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you never actually update the value of your `#hide` element. You need to set its value inside of your event binding (just made the input visible for reference):

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" onblur="var myno = this.value; var concatno=myno.concat('0001'); document.getElementById('hide').value = concatno; console.log(concatno)" />

<input type="text" id="hide" name="hide" value=concatno disabled />
```

It's also worth noting though, that you should generally avoid using obtrusive event handlers. Instead, delegate event handling to external Javascript. This way, your designer doesn't need to understand or even worry about the JS.

Here's an example using unobtrusive handlers:

```js
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('blur', function() {
  document.getElementById('hide').value = this.value.concat('0001');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" />
<input type="text" id="hide" name="hide" placeholder="concatno" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using name/id instead;

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" oninput='hide.value=(this.value + "0001")'  autofocus=''/>
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" />
```

without inline scripts:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let hide = document.querySelector('#hide');
  document.querySelector('#number').addEventListener('input', function() {
    hide.value = this.value + '0001';
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="4" autofocus='' />
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" />
```